# Rendering JSON with GraphQL in GatsbyJS

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I've been stuck for hours and I have no idea what's wrong. I'm new to GraphQL and Gatsby.

I have a JSON file that I'm trying to render. Each object has its own url path. I'm able to query the data with GraphQL, set up CreatePages in my gatsby-node.js file and then query again in my template file, but for some reason I'm only getting `null` in the template file.

I'm pretty sure I'm using gatsby-plugin-transformer-json correctly too. I'm at a loss right now. Any help is much appreciated.

gatsby-node.js

```
/**
 * Implement Gatsby's Node APIs in this file.
 *
 * See: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/
 */

// You can delete this file if you're not using it
const path = require('path');

exports.createPages = ({actions, graphql}) => {
    const { createPage } = actions;
    const postTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/post.js`);
    const projectTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/project.js`);

    return graphql(`{
        allProjectsJson {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                name
                description
                path
              }
            }
          }
        allMarkdownRemark {
            edges {
                node {
                    html
                    id
                    frontmatter {
                        path
                        title
                        date
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }`)
    .then(res => {
        if(res.errors) {
            return Promise.reject(res.errors);
        }
        // blogs
        res.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({node}) => {
            createPage({
                path: node.frontmatter.path,
                component: postTemplate
            })
        })
        // projects
        res.data.allProjectsJson.edges.forEach(({node}) => {
            createPage({
                path: node.path,
                component: projectTemplate
            })
        })
    })
}
```

templates/project.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'
import Layout from "../components/layout"
// import Helmet from 'react-helmet';

export default function Project({data}) {
    const { projectsJson: project } = data;
    // this results in null???
    console.log(data)
    return (
        <Layout>
            <div>
                <h1>Projects!!!</h1>
                <p>One single</p>
            </div>
        </Layout>
    );
}

export const projectQuery = graphql`
  query ProjectByPath($path: String!) {
    projectsJson(path: { eq: $path }) {
        name
        path
        description
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: what's the output of your `allProjectsJson` query in graphiql?

Comment: @DerekNguyen the output using Gatsby's Graphi interface was the JSON data I specified. That was working fine. For some reason, when I queried in my Template file, I received null.

Comment: does it logs out `null` for all of your json nodes, or just one? In your project template, have you tried logging out `props.pageContext` to see if the `path` is correct?

Comment: oh wait, it looks like you're not passing in a context for your json nodes — try `createPage({ path: node.path, context: { path: node.path }, component:.... })`

Answer (score 0):

I decided to simply list the projects rather than be able to link to each one. With that, I simply had to query in the file rather than pass each object through gatsby-node.js and grab the right one in the template file.

```
import React from "react"
// import { Link } from "gatsby"
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import SEO from "../components/seo"

const Projects = ({data}) => (
  <Layout>
    <SEO title="Projects" />
    <h1>Personal Projects</h1>
    {data.allProjectsJson.edges.map((project, index) => {
        console.log(project)
        return (
                <a 
                    key={index} 
                    style={projectContainerStyles}
                    href={project.node.url}
                    target="_blank" 
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                >
                    <h2>{project.node.name}</h2>
                    {project.node.description}
                </a>
            )
    })}
    <p>You can see my external portfolio 
        <a 
            href="https://anthonyzamarro.github.io/az_portfolio/" 
            target="_blank" 
            rel="noopener noreferrer"> 
            here!
        </a>
    </p>
  </Layout>
)

const projectContainerStyles = {
    marginBottom: '2rem', 
    background: 'turquoise', 
    padding: '8px', 
    borderRadius: '5px', 
    boxShadow: '1px 3px 2px rgb(155,155,155)',
    'display': 'block',
    'color': '#000',
    textDecoration: 'none'
}

export const projectQuery = graphql`
  query projectQuery {
    allProjectsJson {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          name
          description
          url
        }
      }
    }
}`
export default Projects
```